# Java testing methods with JUnit

Tags: java, junit

Im new to junit testing, so im asking how those methods should be in junit test?

```
    public void addUser(String username) {
            usernames.add(username);
        }
    public String toString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(name+"\n");
            if ( usernames.size() == 0 ) 
                sb.append("EMPTY\n");
            for ( String user : usernames ) 
                sb.append(user+"\n");
            return sb.toString();
        }
```

Comment: Is your toString method really used in code or just for convenience when logging etc.? If you're not using the return for it you can focus testing your actual business logic...

Comment: Yes, toString is used in the code. I need to test all methods for homework project.. and im noob in junit..

Comment: Well. You know how your output should look like. What's keeping you from [getting started](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Getting-started)?

Answer (score 2):

To give you a start:

```
@Test
public void test1() {
    YourObject o = new YourObject();
    o.addUser("TheUserNameYouWantToTest");
    Assert.assertEquals("YourExpectedString", o.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use assert-methods. You should compare if it is the same what you are expected and what your method returns